# after update VCSA 6.5 to latest patch VCSA is still showing previous ver, but mgmt appliance showing newer ver

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I was updating VCSA vSphere Client version 6.5.0.41000 to latest 6.5.0.42000,
but after reboot : VCSA gui ( in about tab) still showing previous ver 41000,
But in Mgmt. appliance via port 5480 is showing newer ver 42000,
Also powercli check script  showing newer ver. 42000

Any idea what is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Reboot and also upgrade, 6.5's EoSL, even 6.7 will be shortly.

Comment: I realized this difference version reporting also in VCSA 7 , not so frequent, but yes